# In Magento 2 , configurable product options disabled after the first selection.How to reset option?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product

I am using Magento 2, I have some Configurable Products with a lot of variants (in some cases there are 5 attributes, each with several options). Each variant has a Simple Product associated with it, and the prices are set up under the Super Product Attribute Configuration.

Everything looks correct in Admin as far as I can tell.

On the Front end product page, the first time you select your options is fine, some options are disabled (greyed out) based on the choices you select. (For example, a certain Size may not be available in a certain Colour and that Colour may not be available for one if the other choices etc)

However, if you then change your mind, and what to select a different combination of options, you can't do this because some options remain disabled.

You have to reload the page completely, to reset all the options back to 'Choose an option...'.like
[image]

Currently, if I want to change the option value but that value can't be changed as I attached a screenshot so can anybody help? how to do without refreshing page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I can't seem to reproduce the said issue on my local instance.

(This is what I experience on my localhost - https://www.screencast.com/t/cBK1LR4txXGY)

Could you either:

- Upload the CSV for your products (System > Data Transfer : Export > Products) so that I may import it into my localhost and re-test.
- Provide the URL of your instance where I can test this behavior. (Upload a screencast of the issue in case your instance is not publicly accessible?)

Good luck!

Thanks,

Sharath

Answer (score 0):

If the configurable product options are disabled after the first selection in Magento 2, it may be due to an issue with the JavaScript code or a conflict with another extension. Here are a few steps you can take to reset the options:

Clear your browser cache and cookies - Sometimes, caching issues can cause problems with JavaScript, which can affect the behavior of configurable product options. Clearing your browser cache and cookies can help to resolve this issue.

Disable third-party extensions - If you have recently installed a new extension, it may be conflicting with the configurable product options. Disable any third-party extensions that you have installed and see if this resolves the issue.

Check the JavaScript console for errors - Open the browser console and look for any JavaScript errors that might be causing the problem. Fix any errors that you find.

Reindex your site - If the configurable product options still do not work, try reindexing your site. Go to System > Index Management and select all indexes. Then, click on "Reindex" to start the process.

Clear Magento cache - Go to System > Cache Management and select "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage". This will clear the Magento cache and should reset the configurable product options.

If none of these steps work, you may need to investigate further or contact Magento support for additional assistance.